# what is general cause interrupted while queuing ack for Consumer Record?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are using kafka , getting below exception

```
Exception Occured : OnMessage Exception : org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Interrupted while queuing ack for ConsumerRecord
```

what might the reason for this , can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: can anyone answer this please